# React Ionic, Accessing App.tsx method from component defined through Route Component

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router-dom, react-functional-component, high-order-component

I want to ask how to access method "testMethod" that is defined in App.tsx from Home.tsx

This is App.tsx (this component has method with name "testMethod")

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const testMethod = () => {
    console.log('test');
  };
  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonRouterOutlet>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact />
        </IonRouterOutlet>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is Home.tsx

```
import { IonContent, IonPage, IonSplitPane, IonButton } from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ChildComponentProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {}

const Home: React.FC<ChildComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const onSubmit = () => {
    // I want to access testMethod from App.tsx in here
  };
  return (
    <IonContent>
      <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
        <IonPage id="main">
          <IonButton
            expand="block"
            type="submit"
            class="ion-no-margin"
            onClick={onSubmit}
          >
            Test
          </IonButton>
        </IonPage>
      </IonSplitPane>
    </IonContent>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

From Home.tsx, I want to execute method "testMethod" that is defined in App.tsx when user click the button in Home.tsx

I still can't figure how to achieve this, your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/home" exact>
   <Home test={testMethod} />
</Route>
```

In the `Home` component

```
  const onSubmit = () => {
    // I want to access testMethod from App.tsx in here
    props.test()
  };
```